# WPF Browser Authentication is not picked up

Tags: wpf, authentication, webbrowser-control

Hi I am Working on a WPF application where in i have a WPF Browser control which navigates to url "http:...." which takes windows credentials.

Issue Is: when i copy paste the URL it simply performs authentication and works fine. But when naviating from WPF Web browser it is not picking up the Windows creds.

```
 public void StartNavigation()
        {
            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(URL) && webBrowser.Source == null)
                webBrowser.Navigate(new Uri(URL));
        }

<UserControl x:Class="Slb.iDistrict.Prism.Module.JobEmbeddedBrowser.View.JobEmbeddedBrowserView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" Loaded="UserControl_Loaded"
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
    <WebBrowser Name="webBrowser"/>
</Grid>
```

UserControl_Loaded> Event will call the StartNavigation() method.
my Url looks like this: "http://www.test.cmp.com/App/Login/SingleSignon.aspx?Screen=sample&BL=cc&JN=12345"
When i Do Navigate my Browser.Source is reset to some default.aspx page of the site. I assume that it is because of failure in getting Windows authentication information.
I tried to find some help online but not found appropriate results.

What and Where  is the issue?

Comment: Provide code, otherwise we cannot tell you "What and Where the issue is"

Comment: There is no much Code Dom except that the requested Uri and on UserControl Loaded event I call WebBrowser.NavigateUri()

Comment: I don't understand why you have all sorts of conflicting tags on this? Judging by code, this is clearly WPF. I'm removing other tags but feel free to drop a comment if you have a reason to have the change reverted.

Comment: @Maverik Code is WPF but the underlying browser control is same as winforms browser. Hence added those tags in case if somebody have faced similar issue in other environment

Comment: Does the same page work in IE (if possible to test at all)?

Comment: Noseratio: yes it works simply fine in IE. Also I ran a test using Winforms browser in WPF it works perfectly fine. What could be the reason for WPF browser to fail?

Comment: @user841612 yes I'm aware of it but chances of a winforms solution applying to wpf are very slim. Is it a requirement to use this wrapper? Have you considered Awesomium (.net wrapper around chromium)?

Comment: I am not familiar about awesomium, Also the wrapper is the temp solution for now. But should fix it permanantly

Comment: @user841612, try implementing [WebBrowser Feature Control](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18802626/1768303).

Comment: Noseratio: I implemented the feature but no use. Actually i was looking at all the features/keys given there but none reflects my setting or I am not sure what to set. 
One thing i found is Web socket Authentication prompt which doesnot work fine. 
I am  using IE 8 and the site says about IE 10 will it still work?

Comment: Use `8000` for `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` under IE8. Also, have you tried it with IE9/10? It could be just an IE8 bug, after all.

Comment: Try to set principal in the UI thead. Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new WindowsPrincipal(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent())

Comment: WPF WebBrowser may be the worst built in WPF control. I'll second Maverik and suggest using a real control like the Awesomium web browser.

Answer (score 0):

WPF Web Browser has bug: it ignores URL part after '#'. Maybe auth service redirects you to the page with  '#' in url and this redirection fails. For example authentication in vk.com is not working.