# Add support to print & preview HTML in a dialog-based MFC app

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, printing, mfc

I have a two-part question. I need to add supporting for printing to an existing dialog-based MFC project. The document being printed is composed using HTML. I know that I can add HTML-based dialog but how do you add a capability for printing to it?

PS. I need this to be able to set the print page size according to a program's needs.

Comment: Perhaps telling us what you have tried and what went wrong would be a good starting point?

Comment: @EdHeal: I was able to find how to add print and print view support to a view-based MFC app, but I can't figure out how to port it to a dialog based app.

Comment: Why not post the code

Comment: [This](http://marc.durdin.net/2011/07/demystifying-printing-with-the-microsoft-webbrowser-control-and-showhtmldialogex-2/) might be a good starting point.

Comment: @Noseratio: Very nice. Thanks. I need to decipher it from Delphi now... man, that's one ugly language :)

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by the [excellent Marc's Durdin's article](http://marc.durdin.net/2011/07/demystifying-printing-with-the-microsoft-webbrowser-control-and-showhtmldialogex-2/), I've done some more spelunking.
There actually appears to be an easier way to supply custom `DEVMODE` and `DEVNAMES` and print without using an HTML dialog or a custom [IE print template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). That, in turn, should allow to set custom printer, paper size, orientation, etc.

I have a playground WebBrowser ActiveX host project in C++, similar to [this](http://www.wischik.com/lu/programmer/webform.html). I implement `IOleCommandTarget` interface on my OLE site object (`IOleClientSite`). Now here's the interesting part, when printing gets invoked (via Ctrl-P or via [IDM_PRINT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa769937%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)), the browser control calls back the site object as `IOleCommandTarget::Exec(&CGID_DocHostCommandHandler, OLECMDID_PRINT2, &VARIANT(VT_UNKNOWN), NULL)`. The 3rd parameter contains an object which is passed as `IUnknown`, but when queried for `IDispatch` it supports all the same [`__IE_*` properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768551%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), available via `IDispatch::Invoke`:

```
__IE_TemplateUrl (VT_EMPTY)
__IE_ParentHWND (VT_UINT)
__IE_HeaderString (VT_BSTR)
__IE_FooterString (VT_BSTR)
__IE_OutlookHeader (VT_UNKNOWN)
__IE_BaseLineScale (VT_INT)
__IE_uPrintFlags (VT_UINT)
__IE_ContentDocumentUrl (VT_BSTR)
__IE_ContentSelectionUrl (VT_BSTR)
__IE_PrinterCMD_Printer (VT_BSTR)
__IE_PrinterCMD_Device (VT_BSTR)
__IE_PrinterCMD_Port (VT_BSTR)
__IE_BrowseDocument (VT_UNKNOWN)
__IE_TemporaryFiles (VT_ARRAY)
__IE_PrinterCMD_DevNames (VT_I4)
__IE_PrinterCMD_DevMode (VT_I4)
__IE_PrintType (VT_BSTR)
```

I haven't taken this further yet, but I think it should be possible to alter any of the them and return `S_OK` from `IOleCommandTarget::Exec`, and expect the browser control to take in the changes.

I expect it to work in a similar way for [IDM_PRINTPREVIEW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa769938%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) / [OLECMDID_PRINTPREVIEW2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691264%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but I haven't verified that yet. I'll play with this a bit more, as time allows. Meanwhile, you're welcome to try it out and share your results.

Comment: Thanks again. I need to catch up on reading those articles you linked to and I'll post an update...

Comment: A quick follow-up. I'm struggling to find a C++ sample that can illustrate how to use those IE print templates. This article has a lot of verbal info but no source code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250434(VS.85).aspx Am I missing something?

Comment: The MSDN article contains the [link](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/8/3/683DB9FE-8D61-4A3C-B7B8-3169FF70AE9F/printtemplates.exe). There's an app inside, it has [Template Source] button to show the sample print template sources. They did not provide the C++ sources though.

Comment: Yeah. I discovered that. Unfortunately it is too ambiguous without a C++ code. I started looking into it because the `printtemplates.exe` app itself doesn't seem to print anything on my Windows 8 desktop with IE10. So I'm now looking into using a direct Win32 printing into a DeviceContext: http://read.pudn.com/downloads76/sourcecode/windows/system/289362/hwprint.cpp__.htm What do you think about such approach?

Comment: Using DC is classic, but I'm not sure how it can help here. There used to be [IHTMLElementRender::DrawToDC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752273(v=vs.85).aspx), but it's deprecated (and crashing) since Microsoft has implemented GPU rendering with IE9.

Comment: Yes, I saw that. I was able to find `OleDraw` instead that seems to be supported. I'm currently stuck though at determining the size of the HTML document -- width & height in pixels.

Comment: That should not be a problem, if `OleDraw` does what you need, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18907279/1768303). Are you going to print a one-page document, anyway? The whole thing about IE print templates is they allow to properly paginate an HTML document, using `DEVICERECT` and `LAYOUTRECT` elements.

Comment: Thanks. I thought to bypass the multiple page printing issue by finding out the size of a page from a printer and then by splitting the document onto pages manually once its in the DeviceContext (provided that I can find out the size of an HTML document loaded in my web control.) I may go back to using IE print templates if this approach fails. Again, the reason I went away from IE print templates is a very sketchy documentation, plus that Microsoft sample I quoted above didn't really work for me...

Comment: Here's the production IE print template: `res://C:\Windows\System32\en-US\ieframe.dll.mui/preview.dlg`, if you're brave enough to study it :)

Comment: I should admit, you were right about printing to DC. It prints the IE window's client area and not the document :) In other words, it's useless. So I went back to using IE print templates but that didn't go far either. For some reason my test app randomly crashes when I use them. Do you know of any compilable C++ project that can show how to use those IE print templates?

Comment: Right out of my head, I don't. [This](http://resources.webappearance.com/res/appdev/IEPrintTemplates.aspx) looks relevant, but they actually take the-other-way-round approach, by invoking the printing with an <object> hosted by the page itself.

Comment: I might have gotten closer to make it work with print templates. If you read the docs for `IDM_PRINT`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa769937(v=vs.85).aspx it has the `PRINT_WAITFORCOMPLETION` flag that seems to resolve the crashing issue. What I can't figure out is how to use it alongside the print template path. Any ideas?

Comment: It appears there is no documented way of doing it, check [this](http://microsoft.public.windows.inetexplorer.ie5.programming.components.webbrowser-ctl.narkive.com/rrYevX7f/waiting-for-custom-ie-print-templates-to-complete-how).

Comment: Thanks. It's funny I just came off studying that same page :) You don't happen to know where IE's default print template stored, do you?

Comment: I do, check a few comments above :) Enable script debugging in IE options and navigate to `res://ieframe.dll/preview.dlg`.

Comment: @noseratio, do you have a working sample code to illustrate the calling of PRINT2 or PRINTPREVIEW2? If possible, would you mind take a look at my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60419546/mfc-how-to-set-header-and-footer-for-print-preview-programmatically. Thanks.

Comment: @user180574, sorry I don't. We've stopped using the legacy IE-specific stuff long ago.