# MFC: How to set header and footer for print preview (programmatically)?

Tags: winapi, mfc

Setting header and footer works for print using the following command where I add header and footer as parameters.

```
ExecWB(OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DODEFAULT, &parameters, NULL);
```

But I don't know how to do it for **print preview** and I don't seem to find relevant document about that. It seems header and footer can be set manually via OLECMDID_PAGESETUP, but first I don't want to bring up the UI during runtime (and OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER doesn't work somehow), and second I don't know how to set the parameters when calling OLECMDID_PAGESETUP.

Someone also suggests to set print template (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.windows.inetexplorer.ie5.programming.components.webbrowser_ctl/54f5-aQsk6A) without any detail and the reference link is broken.

Comment: Have you seen [Print Preview Architecture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/print-preview-architecture?view=vs-2019)?

Comment: @StriveSun-MSFT I don’t think the MFC print mechanism is related to html browser automation.

Comment: It seems my question is closest to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19098571/webbrowser-print-settings, however most of the links of reference are no longer available. :(

Comment: According to this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18926793/add-support-to-print-preview-html-in-a-dialog-based-mfc-app/18943374#18943374, it might be possible to set up certain callback with OLECMDID_PRINTPREVIEW2? I would be very appreciated if someone can share his experience on that.