# webbrowser add a margin-left when printing html file

Tags: c#, winforms, webbrowser-control

I'm using a webbrowser control in c# to print an html file. When I open the html file with my current navigator (Firefox or chrome), my page is "great", and I have to print it exactlly how I see it. But when I use a webbrowser control in c#, it's like the webbrowser add a "margin-left" property, and my document isn't centred https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTd1a.jpg I also want to remove this "page 1 of 1" and the Title.
I know that the webbrowser control in c# use Internet explorer, that's why I added this in my html file:

```
http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge
```

But this doesn't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

[This MSKB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/267240) should help with headers/footers. Regarding the rendering issues, I would expect `FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION` to have solved those, but I've already suggested that in the comments to [another question of yours](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19024279/1768303). Have you verified that browser emulation actually works? If it does, the following should show `CSS1Compact` for `compatMode`, and `10` or `9` for `documentMode` (depending on your IE version). The document must have both `<!DOCTYPE html>` and `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` declarations for this to work:

```
dynamic document = this.webBrowser.Document.DomDocument;
dynamic navigator = document.parentWindow.navigator;
var info =
    "\n navigator.userAgent: " + navigator.userAgent +
    "\n navigator.appName: " + navigator.appName +
    "\n document.documentMode: " + document.documentMode +
    "\n document.compatMode: " + document.compatMode;
MessageBox.Show(info);
```

**[EDITED]** To control printing layout beyond [@media CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media), you could implement your own [Internet Explorer Print Template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa753280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). That would provide full control over headers, margins, columns, etc. This feature is flexible, but not trival to implement. Some relevant resources:

- [Beyond Print Preview: Print Customization for Internet Explorer 5.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb250434%28VS.85%29.aspx)
- [Print Templates, Part I](http://www.webreference.com/js/column89/index.html)
- [Demystifying printing with the Microsoft WebBrowser control and ShowHTMLDialogEx](http://marc.durdin.net/2011/07/demystifying-printing-with-the-microsoft-webbrowser-control-and-showhtmldialogex-2/)
- [Add support to print & preview HTML in a dialog-based MFC app](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18926793/1768303)

Comment: Visual studio return me a NullPointerException at the first line :/

Comment: Run this code upon [DocumentCompleted](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.documentcompleted.aspx) event, when `webBrowser.Document` does exists.

Comment: Interesting. So, the document is in standard mode, but printed view is still screwed up compared to how it looks on the screen?

Comment: Yeah, maybe it's the printer ?

Comment: If Print Preview (can be invoked via right-click) looks good, then it's printer specific. Anyhow, that's as much as I can help with this issue.

Comment: Right click the webbrowser? Or you mean using webbrowser.ShowprintDialog?

Comment: I meant when that specific page is loaded inside `WebBrowser` control in your own app, do right click on it and select "Print preview".

Comment: Yeah, when I use print preview, the preview is like it's printed, but I can change "resize" the margin.

Comment: I've added some info on how to control margins to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

In fact the problem was with my Internet Explorer options. In fact, in the settings of the print preview, I had 50px of margin, I just had to remove it. I wasted so much time on this x/. I don't understand why I had those weirds settings, I never used IE on that computer. Well, thanks Noseratio.