# Webbrowser word wrap

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control

I am writing small webbrowser in C# and I would like it to wrap works and images, instead of using horizontal scroll bar.
I need something similar to Word Wrap, as in Notepad.
Here is an example:

Chrome:
[image]

My browser:
[image]

I've looked at other topics but many suggest solutions in CSS and dealing with html. 
I was wondering if there is a way to disable that in WebBrowser itself or by using some other method.

To clarify, Scroll Bar is not a problem, I know that it can easily be disabled by:

```
webBrowser1.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
```

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: It is up the HTML to set the body width.  Trying to override that will just produce pages with bad layout.

Comment: The WebBrowser control will display whatever the HTML tells it to display. You can't change that in any practical manner, nor should you try. The WebBrowser control is basically Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In standard HTML mode, images wrap automatically. E.g.:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge"/>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "http://png-4.findicons.com/files/icons/1943/yazoo_smilies/128/big_smile.png";
        container.appendChild(img);
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Noseratio/VzdDW/

You did not post your HTML, so it's hard to guess, but try enabling the standard mode, both for your web page and for `WebBrowser` control (by [implementing browser feature control](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18802626/1768303)).